# Child bone moving parent bone?

Tags: bones

I have created a simple rig of a character that is intended to be modular. The arms of this character are meant to follow the main spine but are also able to be detached. Instead the bones are not only unable to be detached, they also influence the parent bone. I have tried to work around this by using the connected box, copy transform, child of, and copy location, but since the parent bone is animated through IK it does not actually change transformation beyond 0,0,0. Does anyone know why children bone are influencing the parent bone?

Update: the problem seems to be related to the inverse kinematics, When a chain of bones that is not controlled by inverse kinematics is parented to the bone the parent is affected by the movement of the child bone. However, the inverse kinematics of bones that are children but unconnected to the parent bone still influence the movement of the parent bone

Update 2: I have solved the problem, the inverse kinematic bones had the chain length set at 0. This makes Blender think the entire parented spine is part of the bone chain, by setting the chain length in the IK constraints to the amount of bones in the arms I have successfully restricted their IK to the desired areas.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem, You must set the length of the arm in the IK or else it will think the parented bone chain is part of the deformation.